# How to check the size of composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am facing an issue from last few days when i update my laravel composer. It Gives me an error

> mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
>
> mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
>
> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 809508864) (tried to allocate
>   4096 bytes) in
>   phar:///home4/xxxxxx/public_html/greencanteen/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php
>   on line 220

I talked with my hosting server they said they will provide max `memory_limit` upto 256MB. but my composer size is more than that. so plesae tell me how to check composer size on server and how to reduce it.

Comment: What do you mean by "update my laravel composer"? What command do you execute?

Comment: Composer requires at least ~1GB to [work well](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors). Shared hosting service is not greatly suitable for installation as Laravel needs. Do you have access to server's terminal?